# Drag and drop by pen

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, tablet, vcl, pen

I have a program written in Delphi XE7 using the VCL. An important part of the program is to transfer elements of one ListBox into another by "drag and drop" method.

When performing the same operation on a Windows Tablet by means of a pen, the transfer of elements does not happen. Instead, the elements of the initial ListBox are glanced over.

How to achieve the transfer of the elements "by pen", and also "by finger"?

Comment: What does the code, that you have tried with, look like?